# Using a Neo4j 2.1 dataset for Neo4j 3.3

Tags: neo4j

I want to set up the TheMovieDB Large Movie DataSet for Neo4j.

The download link is [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/movie-database/#_download)

Unfortunately, it says download the appropriate dataset dependent on the version.

But the latest version dataset is 2.1 and I have 3.3

Would I be better off downloading Neo4j 2.1 or is there a way of importing this dataset into Neo4j 3.3?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: As you can read, the archive is the data folder. So there is no import.
I presume that if the Neo4j ppl have left it on their website, it must work. Else, this is the occasion to export csv from 2.1 and import into a 3.3

Comment: Hi. I tried replacing the `graph.db` folder and no luck. Database error code 1

Comment: Try to uncomment #dbms.allow_upgrade=true in neo4j.conf and restart. Else ... 2.1 / export etc ...